# Contact API directly from URL in browser

Tags: html, api, url, post

I am trying to understand how POST and/or GET methods work in terms of the actual browser.

I am attempting to contact an API which requires API key, method you wish to use on their side, and an IP address at the minimum.

My original idea was to do something like this:

I feel like I'm on the right track, it does something and gets an error as opposed to telling me the page does not exist. I'm expecting either JSON or XML in response as the API supports both but instead I get this error:

```
This page contains the following errors:
error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

Upon studying the documentation of the API more, I found something saying that methods are called using HTML form application/x-www-form-urlencoded and the resuource models are given as form elements.

I tried researching what that means to see what the problem was and found this site http://www.w3.org/TR/xforms11/ but I'm still unclear.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to mean that the application is expecting a POST method but you're doing a request with a GET method (when you use the querystrings).

Since you can't just do browser requests using POST using the address bar, you may need to:

- Construct a simple JS function that does a xmlhttprequest request using that method instead, and running it from the console;
- Create a simple HTML page that automates the above process, allowing you do make POST calls;
- Using [CURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) instead, which is a great tool for testing those kinds of requests.

Comment: I"ve tried the xmlhttprequest method, my concern/understanding though was that if it will not work by posting it in my browser, it will not work by doing javascript? Perhaps this is untrue. Also, the API says it supports GET as well as POST, so shouldn't it work?

Comment: A request using the address bar is always using GET and other fixed request header parameters, but by using javascript you can set the method yourself and change other header information with `setRequestHeader()`, including changing the content type (which seems to be what the application is complaining about). But if the docs say it should work as GET, then it should be working with a normal address bar/url request (I always use that for API tests)... maybe it allows both methods but always requires that specific content-type on the header. Which is weird (IMO) but possible.

Comment: While we're on the subject, because I have bee nplaying around with the xmlhttprequest function. Could you explain in laymen terms what the setRequestHeader function does? Is this the part where I specify the POST or GET?

Comment: (Short form, for a comment): when you do any http request, you send header information, which contains some meta-parameters about your request. Those includes the "content type" which declares how the data is encoded: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" is somewhat typical for POST, and what your application seems to expect. More info: http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/Servlet-Tutorial-Request-Headers.html